# Can open FIie Upload PopUp Window

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

My page has code here is.

```
    <div class="qq-upload-button upload-img" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;">
    <input type="file" name="file" style="position: absolute; right: 0pt; top: 0pt; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;">
    </div>
```

I wanna click this **qq-upload-button upload-img**
I use Click at css=.qq-upload-button input but it didn't work
If I use my hand to click result is open a file upload popup.
How can I do that in **Selenium IDE** ?
Thank for advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can senKeys to the upload input field, like this

```
 driver.findElement(By.name("file")).sendKeys("your file path");
```

Do not call .clear() on the field, that doesnt work. Than continue(click next button or submit form something like that) and your file will be uploaded.

Comment: What do i do in Selenium IDE?
What command I can use?
thank for support!

Comment: Something like this:<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>name=file</td>
 <td>your file</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>name=continue</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
Continue is a button for example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xpath=(//*[@class="qq-upload-button upload-img"])
```